# Vein extraction from this image

Tags: image-processing, matlab, opencv, image-segmentation, c++

I have this image:

[image]

What methods should I use to extract the veins from this image.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3):

I would like to direct you to 3 references:

> C. Steger: “Extracting Curvilinear Structures: A Differential
>   Geometric Approach”. In B. Buxton, R. Cipolla, eds., “Fourth European
>   Conference on Computer Vision”, Lecture Notes in Computer Science,
>   Volume 1064, Springer Verlag, pp. 630-641, 1996.
>
> C. Steger: “Extraction of Curved Lines from Images”. In “13th
>   International Conference on Pattern Recognition”, Volume II, pp.
>   251-255, 1996.
>
> C. Steger: “An Unbiased Detector of Curvilinear Structures”. IEEE
>   Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence, vol. 20,
>   no. 2, pp. 113-125, 1998.

In these works, Steger develops a subpixel curvilinear structure extraction algorithm, which is found to work very well for such images. I have also run the algorithm on your images and here you go:

**Lines visualized on original image**
[image: Lines visualized on original image]

**Lines only**
[image]

I set the line thickness to 2 for better visualization, normal contours are at sub-pixel level.

Comment: Do you have any implementation references for Steger's method?

Comment: Not that hard to implement actually. But MVTec's Halcon library should have an implementation of it. Though this is an expensive software. A partial open-source version (although suboptimal) is implemented here: https://github.com/songyuncen/EdgesSubPix. Note that this is just an edge detector, but uses similar ideas.

Answer (score 1):

For dealing with images like this in the past, I have always had good luck using the "Vesselness" filter designed by Frangi et al. It utilizes the eigenvectors of the Hessian to determine the probability of a given pixel belonging to a vessel. The code is available on the [MATLAB File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24409-hessian-based-frangi-vesselness-filter) and using the default parameters I was able to get the following result.

```
img = imread('image.jpg');
img = 1 - (img(:,:,1) ./ max(max(img(:,:,1))));
f = FrangiFilter2D(img);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Gabor filter or a difference of gaussians.