# Best way of segmenting veins from arm?

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, image-registration

I have done fews researches and found out approach such as

- multiscale and
- region growing,

that could be used of extracting forearm veins.

However, I tried to use frangi filter and Figure 1 is the segmentation result using the best parameter set I could found;

[image]
Figure 1

Could anyone suggest what approaches as well the technique to adopt while considering this problem?

I give extra image for further analysis:

[image]

Comment: well, you listed a lot of approaches, and you even said "my parametrization might be wrong". Why not adjust parameters then? why not try one of these other approaches if Frangi doesn't help (I don't know Frangi, or much about segmentation, but my point is that you're underdefining your question)?

Comment: i had adjusted the parameter and attached is the best veins extraction that i could obtained, so far i am trying other approaches but i might doing the wrong things and i have only a short time to do it, therefore, i am asking idea from expert here. Thanks again for the comment

Comment: ah, that's a good remark; you could even add that to your question ("this is the segmentation using the best parameter set I could find")!

Answer (score 7):

So one good step to enhance the vein-like structures is coherence enhancing diffusion:

> Weickert, Joachim. "Coherence-enhancing diffusion filtering." International Journal of Computer Vision 31.2-3 (1999): 111-127.

So I first apply this algorithm to your image, aggressively. The next step is to identify the curvilinear structures, which would in this case extract the veins. I already explained how to do this robustly in a [previous post](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/28115/vein-extraction-from-this-image). So please check this.

The result is the following:
[image]

One could apply all the desired noise cleaning to this image. Note that the edges appear very weak, so it is better to tune the parameters, probably even more than I did.